# Need Thread To Block Next Code Line But Not Other Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, blocking

I have a method that uses a thread to connect to my database to check if the user exists on the database. I have another thread that is responsible to update the GUI. I need the database thread to block the code that comes after it until it terminates, but not to block the GUI thread. How do I manage to do that?

I've Tried using the join command, but it blocks the GUI thread. And I've tried using a loop that does nothing until the database thread is not alive, but it blocks too.

```
#GUI Thread
self.guiThread = threading.Thread(group= None, target=self.guiLoop)
self.guiThread.start()

#GUI Method
def guiLoop(self):
    while True:
        self.Update()

#Login Button Method
def onLoginButtonClick(self, event):
    id = self.idBox.GetValue()
    self.idBox.SetValue("")
    password = self.passwordBox.GetValue()
    self.passwordBox.SetValue("")
    self.retList = []
    self.testBool = False
    dbThread = threading.Thread(group= None, target=self.checkUser, args=(id, password, self.retList))
    dbThread.start()
    #TODO Blocking
    print (self.retList)

#Database Thread Method
def checkUser(self, id, password, retList):
    self.retList = DB.checkUser(id,password)
```

DB.checkUser is the method that checks the database if it has the user, and returns a list with user information, or an empty list if it does not have the user on the database.

Comment: What code are you talking about when you say, "the code that comes after it."?

Comment: When you talk about a mutex, don't talk about what _code_ it protects. Code is read-only. Code does not need protection. You should be talking about what _data_ are protected by the mutex instead.

Comment: You want to block `print (self.retList)`? Put it inside the thread and just return after `dbThread.start()`.

Comment: But I need the rest of the code to not run until it finishes the action. I need all code to be blocked (the print(self.retlist) is just an example for the code that needs to be blocked, I need the code outside of the method to run only after an answer from the database was recieved) but I do need the gui thread to run so the gui would not freeze. Is there a way?

Comment: It's beginning to sound as if what you _really_ want is for some GUI widgets to be disabled or inaccessible until the background task is finished. Why not have `onLoginButtonClick(...)` put the GUI into a mostly disabled state, have `checkUser(...)` post an event when it is finished, and have the event handler reenable all of the commands that previously were disabled?

Comment: P.S.: When I say _mostly_ disabled, I mean, you might want to entertain your user with a progress bar, give 'em the option to cancel the background op, the option to quit the program, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution - delayed reaction class fro Wxpython.